# How to set a property by calling a method

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, user-controls

I'd like to know how to set a custom property of a custom user control by calling a method  that would serve as "data provider" for that property.

What I mean is I'd like to write something like this:

`<CatsUserControl Cats={FindAllCats} />`,

where **CatsUserControl** is a User Control I created (which has a Property named **Cats**), and  **FindAllCats()** is a method written in C# that returns a list of Cat objects.

Is this possible?

I appreciate any ideas. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

The whole thing began because I wanted to be able to assign a list to a property in XAML, the same way you do `<Button Content="Value"/>` (except, in my case, Value is a more complex type than a string, it's a `List<KeyValuePair<String, Boolean>>`). 
Because I didn't find any way to do that, I thought it might be possible to call a method that returns this list and assign the returned value to the property instead.

Hope that makes things clearer.

Comment: "FindAllCats is a method", fine but in what context.  Is it a method a on the `CatsUserControl` or is it a method on the object which is the current DataContext or is it a StaticMethod of some type or... the list goes on.  Please clarify, your edit doesn't clear this up.

Comment: One thing I'm struggling with is why anyone would have a desire to have a "FindAllCats" method instead of a "AllCats" property.  If you have a AllCats property its a simple binding.  So __why__ are you implementing AllCats as FindAllCats?  (I understand that this example code but the principle holds).

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: Turns out all I needed was, indeed, a simple binding. The thing is, I wanted to bind the AllCats property to the return value of the FindAllCats method. And I wanted to do that because the "AllCats" property is the property of a UserControl (UC1) that is created, in XAML, in another user control (UC2), and each UC2 that creates the a UC1 has its own FindAllCats method. I apologize for the confusion and for taking so long to post a reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you are trying to do is really just databinding?

In other words, you would approach it like this:

```
<CatsUserControl ItemsSource="{Binding AllCats}" />
```

[Binding to a collection](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/jesseliberty/archive/2008/03/16/tip-of-the-day-binding-to-a-collection.aspx)

If you want to bind specifically to a property called Cats you need to create an object that implements INotifyPropertyChanged, I think. (semi-pseudo code follows):

```
//binding to this public property in the CatsUserControl    
public List<Cat> Cats;


public class BindingToCats : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<Cat> allCats;

    public List<Cat> AllCats
    {
        get { return allCats; }
        set
        {
            allCats = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AllCats");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

and then bind to it with your custom usercontrol:

```
<CatsUserControl Cats="{Binding AllCats, Source={StaticResource BindingToCats}}" />
```

Comment: No, that's not what I need.. I edited my question to better describe what I'm after. Sorry if I wasn't clear before.

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged implementation is only necessary if you need to UI to track changes made to the property.  This is quite a common requirement but isn't absolutely necessary for binding to work.  In cases where the property values are readonly or fixed once the object is initialised, INotifyPropertyChanged is not needed.

Comment: your solution was right all along. The first time I replied I think I was really confused about the problem. Just one remark (really important one): the property (Cats) must be a DependencyProperty. If it's not, binding will not work and you'll get a XamlParseException  (AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE). I didn't know that (I was trying to bind to a regular CLR property), and that's also why I refuted binding as a solution at first. More info on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221408(VS.95).aspx. Thanks again and sorry for the confusion! :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are probably looking for is a [TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter%28VS.95%29.aspx).

Here is an example of how you can set a List< KeyValuePair< String, Boolean>> using a string in attribute syntax in xaml. The Xaml will end up looking something like:

```
<c:CustomButton Values="Hello World,true; Foo,false; Bar,true" />
```

The exact syntax of how you want to represent the list of key/value pairs is up to you.

Here is the code necessary to do this:

```
public class CustomButton : Button
{
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ListOfStringAndBoolPairsTypeConverter))]
    public List<KeyValuePair<String, Boolean>> Values { get; set; }
}

public class ListOfStringAndBoolPairsTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        //TODO: Should add better error handling here.
        var stringValue = (string)value;
        var pairs = stringValue.Split(';').Select(ps => ParsePair(ps));

        var result = new List<KeyValuePair<String, Boolean>>();
        result.AddRange(pairs);
        return result;
    }

    private KeyValuePair<String, Boolean> ParsePair(string pairStringValue)
    {
        var splitString = pairStringValue.Split(',');
        var key = splitString[0];
        var value = Boolean.Parse(splitString[1].Trim());
        return new KeyValuePair<string, bool>(key, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I liked your solution! Not only because it would work in my case, but also because it made me realize that values in XAML don't have to be restricted to a string. I mean, even though ""Hello World,true; Foo,false; Bar,true" is a string, it represents a whole other type to which I can convert it to! The possibilities are endless :D Thanks! Too bad I can't mark two answers as correct..

Answer (score 0):

You ought to be able to do what you're asking by subscribing to events instead of binding directly from the XAML.

Also, you could use a converter, which is described [here](http://jesseliberty.com/2008/10/13/data-binding-%E2%80%93-data-validation/).

Comment: The events idea is good, but I'd like to set all of the control's properties in XAML, so it's clear where those values came from. The converter, OTOH, is a great solution.